# How to build a app real time with without firebase or other library

Tags: android, real-time

I'm making an Android App realtime, but i don't want to use firebase or another library.

I have an API, my idea is request to the API each 3-5 seconds.
My API has written base NodeJS Express.

Any ideas are better than my idea

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use NodeJS on the backend with socket.io
That will open a real time communication between your API and your app

Comment: My API has written base NodeJS Express

Comment: Here you can see how to implement in your backend and a chat example

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/a-simple-messaging-app-with-react-native-and-socket-io-e1cae3df7bda

Comment: An example with react native

Comment: Well, technically, the socket.io is a library, so this answer will not fulfill the requirements. On the other hand, creating a real time app without using any third party tool, will be hard, and definitely not a beginner problem.